# How do we know a new transaction is not corrupted/manipulated?

Tags: blockchain, mining-theory

let's say I want to send a certain amount of bitcoin to a certain client, but my computer is connected to a public wifi, how do I make sure there is not a man in the middle altering the transaction broadcast?

As far as I know, the underlying mechanisms to broadcast operations are not encrypted, how does the network recognize corrupted packets?

Moreover, could a government analyze a traffic and "block" packets that gives hint that a specific packet contains bitcoin-protocol-relevant payload?

Comment: Yes, all traffic on the Bitcoin network is unencrypted, so it's pretty obvious when you're using Bitcoin.

Comment: @Murch But couldnt governments exploit this fact by blocking packages that contain btc-protocol-specific payloads, thus prohibiting bitcoin transaction within the state?

Comment: They could block unencrypted Bitcoin traffic but that wouldn't prevent Bitcoin transactions in their territory. It's not exactly hard to tunnel traffic through a VPN, or onto a privacy network. Also, https://www.bip324.com/.